# Shoot balloons and Collect Maximum Points

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

There are 10 balloons and each balloon has some point written onto it. If a customer shoots a balloon, he will get points equal to points on left balloon multiplied by points on the right balloon. A Customer has to collect maximum points in order to win this game. What will be maximum points and in which order should he shoot balloons to get maximum points ?

Please note that if there is only one balloon then you return the points on that balloon.

I am trying to check all 10! permutations in order to find out maximum points. Is there any other way to solve this in efficient way ?

Comment: What if he shoots the leftmost or rightmost balloon? 0 points?

Comment: If he shoots any balloon on leftmost or rightmost, then 1 point will be multiplied to left or right to it

Comment: I think it can be solved using Dynamic programming with bitmask.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems to be good to always shoot the ballon next (left or right) to the one with the most points. Not sure thogh if this always leads to the optimal solution.

Comment: It will fail in some cases

Comment: @Bhuwan do you have a counter example?

Comment: First what will you do if two balloon have equal points ?
Ex : 10 9 3 7 8
Here you should shoot first 3 to get 9*7 points.But you are shooting 9 first which will get you 30 points.So if you shoot first balloon next to the one with most points here then maximum in above ex will be 9+3+7+8+10 = 37 only which clearly is not maximum.

Comment: Yes, I see. The result will be 190 points but this is still less than what you get shooting 3 first.

Comment: I shot 3 first to just proof that shooting balloons nearest to balloons having highest point won't work. As far as solution is concerned, I am trying to check all permutations and find out maximum which is not efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comments a Dynamic programming solution with bitmasking is possible, what we can do is keep a bitmask where a `1` at a `bit` indexed at `i` means that the `ith` baloon has been shot, and a `0` tells that it has not been shot.

So a Dynamic Programming state of only mask is required, where at each state we can transition to the next state by iterating over all the ballons that have not been shot and try to shoot them to find the maximum.

The time complexity of such a solution would be : `O((2^n) * n * n)` and the space complexity would be `O(2^n)`.

Code in c++, it is not debugged you may need to debug it :

```
int n = 10, val[10], dp[1024];    //set all the values of dp table to -1 initially

int solve(int mask){
    if(__builtin_popcount(mask) == n){
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[mask] != -1) return dp[mask];

    int prev = 1, ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        if(((mask >> i) & 1) == 0){ //bit is not set
            //try to shoot current baloon
            int newMask = mask | (1 << i);
            int fwd = 1;
            for(int j = i+1;j < n;j++){
                if(((mask >> j) & 1) == 0){
                    fwd = val[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
            ans = max(ans, solve(newMask) + (prev * fwd));
            prev = val[i];
        }
    }
    return dp[mask] = ans;
}
```

Comment: In your 2 bitmask tests, change `&&` to `&`.  Otherwise it looks good to me :)

Comment: Solution in Java for N baloons https://gist.github.com/legendjaks/b02a21fc6006359b28a8b51272a2025a

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int findleft(int arr[],int n,int j ,bool isBurst[],bool &found)

{
    if(j<=0)
    {
        found=false;
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=j-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(!isBurst[i])
        {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    found = false;
    return 1;

}

int findright(int arr[],int n,int j,bool isBurst[],bool &found)

{

  if(j>=n)
  {
      found = false;
      return 1;
  }
  for(int i= j+1;i<=n;i++)
  {
      if(!isBurst[i])
      {
          return arr[i];
      }
  }
  found=false;
  return 1;

}
int  calc(int arr[],int n,int j,bool isBurst[])
{
    int points =0;
    bool leftfound=true;
    bool rightfound=true;
    int left= findleft( arr, n-1, j,isBurst , leftfound);
    int right = findright( arr,n-1, j,isBurst, rightfound);
    if(!leftfound && !rightfound)
    {
        points+=arr[j];
    }
    else
    {
        points+=left*right*arr[j];
    }
    return points;


}

void maxpoints(int arr[],int n,int cp,int curr_ans,int &ans,int count,bool isBurst[])
{
    if(count==n)
    {
        if(curr_ans>ans)
        {
            ans=curr_ans;
            return;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(!isBurst[i])
        {
            isBurst[i]=true;
            maxpoints(arr,n,i,curr_ans+calc(arr,n,i,isBurst),ans,count+1,isBurst);
            isBurst[i]=false;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int ans=0;
    int arr[n];
    bool isBurst[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
        isBurst[i]=false;
    }
    maxpoints(arr,n,0,0,ans,0,isBurst);
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```